# Python: Getting text of a Regex match

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex match object in Python. I want to get the text it matched. Say if the pattern is `'1.3'`, and the search string is `'abc123xyz'`, I want to get `'123'`. How can I do that?

I know I can use `match.string[match.start():match.end()]`, but I find that to be quite cumbersome (and in some cases wasteful) for such a basic query.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: [`re.finditer()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: @Elazar judging by the question, the OP knows how to obtain `MatchObject`s, but not how to easily get their contents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get only the matched text in Python?](/q/14936971/90527)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use the match object's `group` function, like:

```
match = re.search(r"1.3", "abc123xyz")
if match:
    doSomethingWith(match.group(0))
```

to get the entire match. **EDIT:** as thg435 points out, you can also omit the `0` and just call `match.group()`.

Addtional note: if your pattern contains parentheses, you can even get these submatches, by passing `1`, `2` and so on to `group()`.

Comment: Unintuitive in my opinion... But I guess that's the best that Python provides.

Comment: @RamRachum I don't think it's too odd. When you do regex replacements you refer to the capturing groups with `\1`, `\2` and so on (or `$1`, `$2`, depending on implementation), and the entire match is often referred to by using `\0` (or `$0`). So it's consistent with that numbering of groups.

Comment: You can omit `0`, just `match.group()`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the regex inside "()" to be able to get that part

```
>>> var = 'abc123xyz'
>>> exp = re.compile(".*(1.3).*")
>>> exp.match(var)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x691738>
>>> exp.match(var).groups()
('123',)
>>> exp.match(var).group(0)
'abc123xyz'
>>> exp.match(var).group(1)
'123'
```

or else it will not return anything:

```
>>> var = 'abc123xyz'
>>> exp = re.compile("1.3")
>>> print exp.match(var)
None
```

Comment: I don't think using `.*(...).*` for substring matches is a good practice. Just use `search` instead of `match` and it does all the for you. In fact, it's even superior, as you won't be able to get multiple matches with `match` (instead it will return the last one, which is also quite intuitive, as opposed to the first one).